# C - read a string of numbers

Tags: c, string, numbers, int

I want to read a string of numbers (only intigers) that I don't know and also I don't know how many of these numbers I will have to read. Each will be separated by whitespace. So waht is the best way to do it?

You don't have to write me a code or something, I just want to know what  should I use.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this might work

```
int main(){

    char name[100];
    printf("Insert numbers: ");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    printf("Your numbers: %s\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read character by character. Everytime you find number(character from 48 to 57), add to temporary string. When you have whitespace, try to parse created string. Then empty it. And continue it till the end of the big string.

Comment: Thanks, one of my thoughts was something similar, at least I now that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read in a loop, skipping the blank spaces (see `isspace(3)`) and in an inner loop, `while (isdigit(getchar()))`  (see `isdigit(3)`)

I'll write some code  (if you don't want to be spoiled out, don't read below until you are satisfied with your solution):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* this macro calculates the number of elements of an array.
 * you must be carefull to always pass an array (not a pointer)
 * to effectively get the number of elements */
#define SIZE(arr) ((sizeof arr) / (sizeof arr[0]))

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int a[100];
    /* this has to be an int (not a char) see getchar() manpage */
    int last_char = 0;

    /* while n < number of elements of array a */
    while (n < SIZE(a)) {

        /* read the character into last_char and check if it is
         * a space, tab or newline */
        while (isspace(last_char = getchar()))
            continue;
        /* last_char is not a space, it can be EOF, a minus sign,
         * a digit, or something else (not a number) */

        if (last_char == EOF)
            break; /* exit the outer loop as we got no more input data */

        int neg = (last_char == '-'); /* check for negative number */
        if (neg) last_char = getchar(); /* advance */

        /* check for digits */
        if (isdigit(last_char)) {
            /* digits are consecutive chars starting at '0'.  We are 
             * assuming ASCII/ISO-LATIN-1/UTF-8 charset. This doesn't
             * work with IBM charsets. */
            int last_int = last_char - '0';
            while (isdigit(last_char = getchar())) {
                last_int *= 10;  /* multiply by the numeration base */
                last_int += last_char - '0'; /* see above */
            }
            /* we have a complete number, store it. */
            if (n >= SIZE(a)) { /* no more space to store numbers */
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "No space left on array a. MAX size is %d\n",
                    SIZE(a));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (neg) last_int = -last_int;
            a[n++] = last_int;
        }

        /* next step is necessary, because we can be on a terminal and
         * be able to continue reading after an EOF is detected.  Above
         * check is done after a new read to the input device. */
        if (last_char == EOF)
            break;
    } /* while (n < SIZE(a) */

    printf("Number list (%d elements):", n);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
} /* main */
```